# How do I prevent my openvpn gateway from becoming unreachable through ssh?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, routing, openvpn

I'm using this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/superjamie/ac55b6d2c080582a3e64, to set up a vpn gateway in my network. The `.ovpn` config of my provider uses the `pull` option to set routes on the client, and this is giving me some problems.

As soon as I enable the openvpn connection, the machine becomes unreachable with ssh from my local network (I assume because it's pulling routes that are isolating it from my local network). I've removed the `pull` option, and that helps, but then the openvpn connection no longer works as expected (because it doesn't have the proper routes).

So how do I prevent the machine from routing ssh traffic over the vpn connection (which I assume is what's making it unreachable), whilst still pulling the other routes (so that the connection works)?

Comment: I should add that it is still reachable through ssh for machines on the same subnet (192.168.1.x). It's just no longer reachable for machines from anywhere else.

Comment: Is "anywhere else" limited to the rest of your LAN (i.e. a specific prefix), or do you need it to continue working globally as well? Additionally, what OS are the client machines running?

Comment: Currently anywhere else is 192.168.2.x. Other than vpn return traffic it shouldn’t be reachable for other networks. Client machines are running ios, android and macos.